# JMS Application giving error

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, jms

I'm trying to run some applications (both my own and tutorial-applications) to help me understanding the basics of JMS. The code in the applications should be correct (for at least some). My added libraries are: `Java EE 6 API Library - javaee-api-6.0.jar`, `jndi-properties.jar`, `appserv-rt.jar`, `javaee.jar` and `JDK 1.7(Default)`.

But with every single application I try to start, I get the following error message:

```
run:
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:488)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Note that it does say `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, but it's a runnable form class (with 2 textfields and a button) and I don't see my form.

I'm trying my applications in NetBeans 7.1.1 using GlassFish Server 3.1.2 1. I've configured the used connection factories and destination resources in the admin console.

As seen by other related questions, I've tried moving the `javaee.jar` up and down the classpath, and even removed it, with no results. The same goes for `Java EE 6 API Library`, but that jar is needed for my project.

Comment: Remove all libraries. Under Libraries folder in NetBeans projects window you have to see only JDK and GlassFish Server 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `javaee-api-6.0.jar` to `javaee-api-5.0.5.jar` fixed it.